# how to write custom function which can be implemented on all columns at a time in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, aggregate-functions, custom-function

I know how to write the custom function which can be applied on all columns at a time in pyspark.
Below are the steps:
1)In pyspark i change the data structure using explode function, for example if i have 10 columns i change it to two columns, one column represent the columns name, 2nd column will represent actual column value.so lets say with 10 columns i have 100 rows, after explode it will change to 10*100=1000 rows with 2 columns
2)then i apply grouped pandas udf(grouping by the column1 which contains column names) , where i implement my custom logic, for example i pass a dataframe with two columns to the pandas udf and then in the pandas udf i create four to five columns based on the initial two columns, then i sum up the last columns and return a single numeric value.

I am trying to find similar option in scala, and i though i can go with UDAF/aggregator but later i realized that it works in a different way, and i cannot create columns inside UDAF, which is one of my core requirement.

Comment: can you include the code of your udf to see if it is posible to do with an UDAF?